# Kendo Pdf export

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am doing page break by grouped column and I need to add Grouped column value to Page header. How can access the grouped column value from page header template and  render it?

Comment: Can you show how your are doing the page break ?

Answer (score 0):

The grid feature pdf-export only surfaces two variables at the render time of the header and footer template. Available template variables include:

- pageNum
- totalPages

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/pdf.template

The variables become available in a kendo compiled template, which is an anonymous function.  The function does not have access to the caller and thus you don't know anything more about the state of the render process at the time of header/footer rendering.  Kendo may be doing things serially, or could be adding the headers/footers later after the grid is wholly rendered -- you just don't know (unless you are licensed and want to dig into the PDFDocument component source code)

[This dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@RichardAD/ocOqezOL) is an experiment that uses `pageNum` and `totalPages` and also tried to track the render process via a dummy column.  The tracking attempt did not work out.

```
{ field: "dummy", title: " ", width:1, template: "#computeDummy(data)#" }

    function computeDummy(data) {
      window.SupplierID = data.SupplierID;
      window.CategoryID = data.CategoryID;
      // console.log (data.SupplierID + " : " + data.CategoryID + " " + data.ProductName);
    }
```

And use the (globally) tracked data in the grids pdf header/footer template.

```
pdf: { …
            template: kendo.template($("#my-page-template").html()),
              margin: { top: "1.25cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "1cm", left: "1cm" },
} 

<script type="x/kendo-template" id="my-page-template">
    <div class="page-template">
        <div class="header">
            <div style="float: right">Page #:pageNum# of #:totalPages#</div>
            This is a header.  Last rendered: SupplierID=#=window.SupplierID# CategoryID=#=window.CategoryID# #console.log(data)#
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            This is a footer.
            Page #:pageNum# of #:totalPages#
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

The timing of the pdf rendering and html (browser) rendering are likely affected by internal promise resolutions and **don't** line up in way that can leveraged during pdf generation.